# Firebase realtime database: using limitToLast returns a list with one null value, and then an actual value

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a query inside a Flutter application. I am having a bit of trouble getting values from a certain node in my firebase realtime database. I'm using the following query

```
final snapshot = await databaseRef
          .child("condicionPago")
          .orderByChild("co_cond")
          .equalTo("PTOCON")
          .limitToLast(1)
          .get();
```

With this, I am expecting to get a list with 1 element that has the value "PTOCON" for the key "co_cond". Problem is, I am receiving a list with **two** elements: a null element, and the element I am actually looking for. Like so:

```
[
    null,
    {
        "co_cond": "PTOCON",
        //...other properties from the node
    }
]
```

I have the same problem when using the following modifiers doing a test in postman
`...orderBy="co_cond"&equalTo="PTOCON"&limitToLast=1`

and also with this one

`...orderBy="co_cond"&startAt="PTOCON"&endAt="PTOCON"&limitToLast=1`

Since my code is expecting precisely one value from that list, it starts throwing an exception when it shows up.

I tried removing the `limitToLast()` modifier from my query, but inside the app, the problem persists. However, removing it from the postman test solves the problem, returning a key from the parent node and the value, like so

```
{
    "1": {
        "co_cond": "PTOCON",
        //...
    }
}
```

I can also filter the null value after I receive the response, but I don't think that's the right idea. I feel like I am doing something wrong with my query and I do not see it. Any help, any explanation, will be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using small numerical values as the keys in your database, which unfortunately means that Firebase SDKs and API interpret them as array indexes. There is no way to disable this behavior.

The solution is to not use pure numerical values as keys, for example by prefixing them with a short string, e.g. `key_1`, `key_2`, etc.

For more on this, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).